# Amazon 'Login with Amazon' works in browser or postman, but not from cUrl or python

Tags: django, python-social-auth, http-status-code-503, login-with-amazon

I described the issue fully here:
https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/497

And I will copy it here. The full context is that I'm experiencing a failure with the Amazon backend provider for the Django third party library python-social-auth.

(https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon.html)

The specific context is not really relevant however to the core issue, which is that Amazon does not honor requests without a User-Agent in the header.

**Expected behaviour**

Authentication with Amazon should work the same as any other backend like Facebook or Google. Particularly the call to https://www.amazon.com/ap/user/profile? should return a response:
https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/backends/amazon.py#L37

[Login With Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/web-docs.html)

**Actual behaviour**

(Even beyond the scope of python-social-auth/social-core) when sending a request to https://www.amazon.com/ap/user/profile, requests fail from python code or cUrl commands, while they succeed from Postman or Web browsers.

Adding a 'User-Agent' to the headers in cUrl or in python fixes this issue such that I can request profile data and I get a successful response.

What are the steps to reproduce this issue?

Once you have a valid access_token from Amazon

you can try this with and without the 'user-Agent' header:

```
import requests

url_str= 'https://www.amazon.com/ap/user/profile?access_token=<your-access-token>'

headers = {    
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url=url_str, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Any other comments?

This seems like an issue with Amazon, but who knows whether or not they will address this. I'm not sure where to send this issue to their side.

Comment: Blocking requests without a User-Agent was most likely intentional, Amazon is under no obligation to support third party packages

Comment: Here's my fix. I created my own `backends.py` file inside of my own app and refer to that inside of my Django settings.py file. In my version it's exactly the same as the one in the `python-social-auth` module, except I added this: `headers={'User-Agent': ''})` and it works now. I can log in and I'm using the same flow and pattern as my other Social Auth providers (FB and Google)

Comment: Ah it's an old api. I was going to add a fix, but someone already has a PR that's hitting the correct endpoint and that endpoint is not as finicky about User-Agent, doesn't need it.
https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/pull/496